# How many complements are in "I blame him for the failure of the report"?

Tags: complements

Complement means required by the head. How many internal complements are required in the below sentence?

> I blame him for the failure of the report.

and is it possible to say "I failed the report"?

Comment: A reference to *the failure of the report* implies ***the report failed*** (to achieve whatever it was supposed to do). Nothing to do with **I**, **him** or anyone else "failing" it (a rather odd usage which could only mean *I/he assigned a "fail" grade to the report*).

Comment: +1 Interesting question. It would be interesting to see whether people thought that *for the failure of the report* was a complement or an adjunct (read adverbial) here. Let's see if any poeple interested in grammar decide to reopen this question ...

Comment: @Araucaria I voted to reopen, mainly to see your argumentation as to the status of the PP in the example as to whether it is a complement or an adjunct. :)

Answer (score 2):

For the purposes of this post, unless stated otherwise, the word *complement* only refers to internal complements of the verb.

> I blame him for the failure of the report.

A complement is a phrase which fills a slot set up by another word in a sentence. It is often said that complements are obligatory, but this is not quite true. The real situation is a bit more complicated. For example, take the verb *teach*. This can have two complements:

- I teach [students] [karate].

Here the words *students* and *karate* are complements of the verb. The verb *TEACH* allows a slot for a learner of some description and a subject of some description too. We can contrast this with the verb *LEARN*, for example which only allows a slot for a topic or subject, but not one for a learner (not an internal one):

- I learned English.
- *I learned myself English. (ungrammatical in standard English)

Notice though that these complements are not obligatory. If someone asks me what I do for a living, I can say simply:

- I teach.

Here the verb *TEACH* has no complements. The sentence is still perfectly grammatical. But as we have seen, the verb "TEACH" *can* have complements. For this reason, it's not quite true that complements are obligatory.

Now, we can contrast complements, words that fill a special slot, with adjuncts. Adjuncts are bits of a phrase or sentence, that do not fill one of these special slots. They are just extra bits of information.They do not have any special relationship with the head word in a phrase. For example, take the phrase *on Mondays* in the following sentence:

- I teach students karate on Mondays.

This phrase *on Mondays* has no special relationship with the verb *teach*. We can stick this phrase on to all kinds of sentences, in fact almost any sentence and it will still be grammatical:

- I am Araucaria on Mondays.

Notice as well that sentences like these will be grammatical with or without this type of phrase. There is no special relationship between *on Mondays* and the verb *BE*.

There are all kinds of tests we can do to see if a phrase is a complement of a verb or an adjunct. My favourite test with action verbs, however, is this: if we replace the verb phrase in a sentence with the pro-verb *DO*, and the pronoun *it* or *this*, then the complements have to disappear, they are replaced by *do it* or *do this*:

- I teach students karate.
- I do this.
- I do it.

If we add the complements back on to the *do it* phrase, the sentence will change it's meaning or be ungrammatical:

- *I do it karate. (ungrammatical)
- *I do it students. (ungrammatical)

If we do the same test with adjuncts, we can add the adjunct back onto the end of the sentence and it will still be good:

- I teach students karate on Mondays.
- I do it.
- I do it on Mondays.

Here we have put *on Mondays* back into the sentence and it is still grammatical. It also still has the same meaning. This shows that *on Mondays* is not a complement of the verb.

**The Original Poster's example**

The only verb in this sentence (and therefore the head of the verb phrase) is the word *blame*. It has an external complement, which is not important in terms of the Original Poster's question, which the subject of the sentence, *I*. It's external because it does not appear within the verb phrase itself.

The verb *blame* has a direct object, "*him*". This is a complement of the verb. The verb *BLAME* sets up a slot for a person or thing. It also has a slot for a phrase which explains a bad thing which that person is responsible for. In the Original Poster's example, this phrase is "*for the failure of the report*". This means that this phrase is a complement of the verb.

Let's use a *do it* substitution to test this theory and see what happens. We can contrast *for the failure of the report* with an adjunct. I'm going to use the adjunct *every single day*:

- I blame him for the failure of the report every single day.
- I do it every single day.
- *I do it for the failure of the report. (ungrammatical or different meaning)
- *I do it him (ungrammatical)

Because we cannot put *for the failure of the report* back into the sentence when we use *do it*, it must be a complement not an adjunct. There are other reason to think this is true. Firstly, *for the failure of the report* is a preposition phrase. The head preposition here is the word *for*. This definitely seems to have a special relationship with the verb *BLAME*. We need to use a phrase with *for*, not just any preposition phrase:

- *I blame him at the failure of the report. (ungrammatical)
- *I blame him of the report. (ungrammatical)
- *I blame him by the report. (ungrammatical)

Also we cannot just add this preposition phrase to any sentence:

- *I am Araucaria for the failure of the report. (ungrammatical)

Notice that we *can* do this with the adjunct *every single day*:

- I am Araucaria every single day.

This seems to show that this *for* preposition phrase is indeed a complement of the word *blame*.

One last piece of evidence that *for the failure of the report* is a complement and not an adjunct, is that usually we can move adjuncts from the end of a sentence to the beginning and the sentence will still sound perfectly fine. If we move complements to the beginning, the sentence will sound strange, it will sound "*marked*":

- I blame him for the failure of the report every single day.
- Every single day I blame him for the failure of the report.
- I blame him for the failure of the report.
- #For the failure of the report I blame him. (very strange)

In the examples above, the adjunct *every single day* can appear at the beginning or end of the sentence and it still sounds good. When we move the complement *for the failure of the report* to the beginning, the sentence sounds very odd. We definitely need a very special reason to organise the sentence in this way. This also seems to show that *for the failure of the report* is a complement, not an adjunct.

There is one last thing we need to think about. Perhaps *of the report* is a separate complement of the verb *blame*. Maybe the sentence is organised like this:

- I blame [him] [for the failure][of the report].

We can show that this is not correct. The string *of the report* is part of the noun phrase *the failure of the report*. We can show this by substituting the noun phrase with the pronoun *it*:

- I blame him for it.

In the example above, we can see that the pronoun *it* means "*the failure of the report*". It must replace the whole noun phrase. If *of the report* was a separate complement of the verb, we would be able to organise the sentence like this:

- I blame [him] [for it] [of the report]

However, this is ungrammatical, because the phrase *of the report* is inside the complement beginning with *for*. More specifically, it is inside the noun phrase which is inside the *for* complement. The sentence is organised like this:

- I blame [him] [for the failure of the report].

So to answer the Original Poster's first question: there are two internal complements of the verb in this sentence.

Regarding the Original Poster's second question, we can say *I failed the report*. This would usually mean that the report had to be officially assessed by you, and it could either pass or fail. You decided to fail it. There are other possible meanings, but this is the most natural one. I don't think this is the meaning that the Original Poster was really asking about, so perhaps the real answer is that we cannot use this sentence to mean the same thing ans the original sentence.

*Hope this is helpful!*

Comment: +1. Nice post for showing how to determine constituency. :)